# Pyinstaller creates exe from python code, but the dependencies are not correctly imported

Tags: python, dependencies, pyinstaller

Maybe you can help me!

I'm going to create a bootstrapper that will run a Python package. I've already created the installer.

I have added Python setup to the installer, but the user should already uninstall his Python, if installed, because the exact version of Python should be installed and be added to the Path.

Instead, I am going to create an executable (exe) from the python code, using "pyinstaller" .

The problem is, the code has some dependencies to the code in the subfolders,
e.g.

```
from .cli.login import login
```

The executable will be created, but the user will get an error:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Do you have any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the dependencies with the exe.

Here's an example:

```bash
pyinstaller --add-data "lib;lib/" script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2560

I need to make sure that all imports are absolute (not relative)